# Xcode set up with Appium

Tags: xcode, appium, xcode6, appium-ios, appium-java

WebDriverAgentRunner

Getting this error after updating the Product Bundle Identifier in Build Settings while updating the bundle

'maximum App ID limit has been reached. You may create up to 10 App IDs every 7 days.'

Because of this error couldn't proceed further with app testing in XCode

[Xcode Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxBf2.png)

Comment: try to change bundle id to yours like: com.akash.auto.webdriver
if still reaching limit, use anther apple id

Comment: getting this error after editing the bundle id - 'There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Select a device run destination to have Xcode register it.'

Comment: check this tutorial https://docs.katalon.com/docs/legacy/katalon-studio-enterprise/create-tests-and-projects/configure-test-cases/mobile-testing/ios/mobile-install-webdriveragent-for-real-ios-devices

Comment: resolved all issues could launch WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj from XCode simulatior,  But failed to launch from simulator getting error "[XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65"